# Can I configure the D7000 to perform lens distortion corrections on the embedded JPEG in the RAWs it saves?

Tags: lens, nikon-d7000, distortion

Lightroom eats the distortion present in the D7000's kit lens for lunch. However, it's time consuming to check which photos I like by performing this correction on all the photos in lightroom first. Ideally, I'd like to be able to view the images on the rear LCD screen with this kind of distortion already corrected.

Is that possible through some switch I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No. It is not possible on the D7000.**

Even though the D7000 can do it on JPEGs, it is questionable to do so on a DSLR. If you did that on the RAW preview, you would get a different image compositionally-speaking from the embedded thumbnail than the RAW.

This is a feature much better suited for SLDs and both Panasonic and Olympus have implemented it in the Micro Four-Third cameras. This is because the preview is digital and therefore is taken into account in the viewfinder. Otherwise you would not be able to frame correctly since distortion correction changes the framing of your images.

Comment: Hmm.. never thought of looking at it that way.  Batch processing in lightroom it is. :)

Answer (score -2):

No, the camera would need a database of all the thousands of possible lenses you could mount on it and the corrections that'd need to be performed on them.
It would also need a powerful CPU and a lot of memory to perform the calculations and hold the data.
That would require a lot of power, your battery would be empty in minutes and the camera red hot.

Comment: I'm not saying it has to be as good as what's possible in lightroom. I don't see why this should be more computationally intensive than several of the other image processing features already on the camera, such as Active D-Lighting or the builtin HDR feature. (Or, for that matter, 1080p/24 video encoding in H/.264)

Comment: After spending some more time playing with the camera, I really don't buy this argument. The camera actually already does have settings like this. Issue is, that you have to do them after taking the shot -- I don't see a place to make any distortion correction be the default setting for the embedded JPEGs. Therefore I really don't buy the CPU power argument -- the corrections the camera can do after the shot are instant and drain the battery less than running the LCD on the back does. I won't downvote this 'cause I don't think it's malicious, but it's almost certainly not correct.